# SSIS scheduler is unable to access file on a remote location

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ssis, remote-access

I have a log file which is placed on a remote drive.
I am just reading this file from my SSIS job and scanning it for errors.
I have ran this job on my local machine it worked fine.
but when I tried to schedule it on a server.
the ssis job is getting failed and it is throwing error that "Access to file denied"
I have tried to run the job under a different user still it gave the same error.
I can access this remote file using file explorer from the server where i have scheduled this SSIS package.
I think there is some issue when the SSIS scheduler is trying to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the SQL Server Agent that runs the jobs has permissions to the files.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS runs with the credentials it was started with.

Have you checked the following for the above user account:

- Share Permission
- Folder Permission
- File Permission